# trying to get only one row from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, distinct-on

I have a problem with DISTINCT ON. I have five different groups of people which include names and surnames. My goal is to get only one name per group (the first one). When try to use DISTINCT ON, I got an error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_A) surname FROM table
```

I want my table to look like

```
group_A...surname_a
broup_B...surname_b
.
.
.
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is specific to Postgres, so I added that tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you've added the `psql` tag, which is specific to the PostgreSQL shell, which doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in Postgres would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_A) group_A, surname
FROM table
ORDER BY group_A;
```

Comment: Thank very much. I am not using Postgres yet, is there any possibility how to write it in other softwares (I am using Navicat)?

Comment: @betdavid1 . . . Navicat is an interface to databases, not a database itself.